# Tensorflow prefetch_to_device

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I try the new tensorflow function tf.contrib.data.prefetch to device.

My simple code example

```
model = build_network()

N=1000

def gen():
    while True:
        batch = np.random.rand(N, 48, 48, 3)
        # Do some heavy calculation
        yield batch

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(gen, tf.float32)
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.prefetch_to_device('/gpu:0'))

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
x = iterator.get_next()

output = model(x)

g = gen()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    for i in range(100):
        if i == 50:
            start = time.time()
        result = sess.run(output)
        #result = model.predict(next(g))
    end = time.time()
print('\nAverage time of one forward pass: {}\n'.format((end-start)/50))
print('Done')
```

This gives the error:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Cannot assign a device
>   for operation 'IteratorGetDevice': Could not satisfy explicit device
>   specification '/device:GPU:0' because no supported kernel for GPU
>   devices is available. Colocation Debug Info: Colocation group had the
>   following types and devices:  IteratorToStringHandle: CPU 
>   IteratorGetDevice: CPU  OneShotIterator: CPU
>
> Colocation members and user-requested devices:   OneShotIterator
>   (OneShotIterator)    IteratorGetDevice (IteratorGetDevice)
>   /device:GPU:0   IteratorToStringHandle (IteratorToStringHandle)
>
> Registered kernels:   device='CPU'
>
> [[Node: IteratorGetDevice =
>   IteratorGetDevice_device="/device:GPU:0"]]

Is this new function not useable in combination with from_generator or is it something else?

Comment: You need to show a little more about how is your model. If the first operation in your model is in the CPU it doesn't make sense to load the data in any GPU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the TensorFlow 1.8rc0 release candidate. Thanks for bringing it to our attention!

It is now fixed in the [master branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/ee3669301e3a6e2c9945124851c5a6b2ee74fe2b) and will be picked up in the next nightly build. I have also filed a [cherry-pick to the 1.8 release branch](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/18624), and it should be included in the next release candidate (and final release) for TensorFlow 1.8.